# Is it a good idea to have a read connection point to both write database and read replica?

Tags: postgresql, replication, amazon-rds, master-slave-replication, load-balancing

In my laravel app I have a write connection to a write database, and a read connection to a dns server that is connected to a single read replica (as [instructed here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/requests-rds-read-replicas/)) In the past the dns server was connected to two read replicas but I removed one to cut costs.

It happened that the only read replica I had had a physical failure and had to restart, in that time my whole system went down. I was wondering if it's a good idea to make read connection point to the dns server, which in turn points to both the read replica that I have and the write database as depicted here:

[image]

Comment: The answer may depend on why you have a read replica in the first place.

Comment: I have a read replica for scalability